# AngularJS, Leaflet. How can I get lat and lon coordinates dynamically from a third-party service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, geolocation, leaflet

I have a simple app shows your current location via the lat and lon coordinates and displays on the map.
But at the moment it is static and coordinates must be specified manually.
Full code of app:

1. index.html

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title></title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-leaflet-directive/0.10.0/angular-leaflet-directive.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
   </head>
       <body ng-app="NearMeApp">

           <div class="header">
               <div class="container-fluid">
                   <h1 class="pull-left">NearMe</h1>
                   <a class="pull-right" href="#/about">About</a>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div ng-view></div>

           <script src="js/app.js"></script>

           <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
           <script src="js/controllers/AboutController.js"></script>

       </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. main.css on [pasteBin](http://pastebin.com/MMfh8dxy)
3. main.html

   ```
   <div class="main">
       <div class="container-fluid" id="map-canvas">
           <leaflet center="mapCenter"></leaflet>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. about.html

   ```
   <div class="about">
       <div class="container-fluid">
           <h1>Meet NearMe</h1>
           <h2>The best place to discover new places around you.</h2>
           <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/">Start exploring</a>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```
5. app.js

   ```
   var app = angular.module('NearMeApp', ['ngRoute', 'leaflet-directive']);

   app.config(function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider
       .when('/', {
           controller: 'MainController',
           templateUrl: 'views/main.html'
       })
       .when('/about', {
           controller: 'AboutController',
           templateUrl: 'views/about.html'
       })
       .otherwise({
           redirectTo: '/'
       });

   });
   ```
6. AboutController.js

   ```
   app.controller('AboutController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

   }]);
   ```
7. MainController.js

   ```
   app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

       $scope.mapCenter = {
           lat: 40.741934,
           lng: -74.004897,
           zoom: 17
       };

   }]);
   ```

How can I get lat and lon dynamically from a third-party service? For example, from [JSON IP API](http://ip-api.com/json)

I've heard that can get the JSON data in a way

```
app.factory('latlon', ['$http', function($http) {
    return $http.get('http://ip-api.com/json')
        .success(function(data) {
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            return err;
        });
}]);
```

but I do not know what to do and how to use it in my situation.
Could you help me solve this problem?

---

#### Solved

issue resolved

MainController.js

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.mapCenter = {};
    $http.get('http://ip-api.com/json')
        .success(function(data) {

            $scope.mapCenter.lat = data.lat;
            $scope.mapCenter.lng = data.lon;
            $scope.mapCenter.zoom = 17;

        });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by '*How can I make sure that the data (Lat and Lon) came dynamically*', but you could utilize the [HTML5 geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) function: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success[, error[, options]])`

You should abstract this into a seperate service or factory to make it more reusable and to avoid dependecy to `window`

```
angular.module('app', []).factory('GeolocationService', ['$q', '$window', function ($q, $window) {

    function getPosition() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (!$window.navigator.geolocation) { // check if geolocation is supported
        deferred.reject('Geolocation is not supported.');
        return;
    }

    $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( // get the current position 
        function (position) { // ok
            deferred.resolve(position);
        },
        function (err) { // error
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

    return deferred.promise; // returned as a promise
  }

  return {
    getCurrentPosition: getCurrentPosition
  };
}]);
```

You could then call it from you controller something like this

```
geolocationSvc.getPosition().then(
   function success(position){
     $scope.mapCenter = {
      lat: pos.coords.latitude,
      lng: pos.coords.longitude,
      zoom: 17      
}, 
function error(err){
  console.log('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
});
```

Note that this code has not been actually tested, but should provide you with an outline of how this could be implemented.

Comment: `Not quite sure what you mean by 'How can I make sure that the data (Lat and Lon) came dynamically'` Yes, it's my typo. I mean that I want to get lat and lon dynamically from a third-party service (the same thing I mean in my question title). And writes these values respectively in `$scope.mapCenter = { lat: lat, lng: lon, zoom: 17 };`